# Implement Cascaded Dropdowns without using Lookups

Tags: 2010, spservices, jquery-ui

I have 3 lists with a great deal of data in them (7-12k rows) that I'm pulling from another system.  I want to implement cascaded dropdowns between the three, but I can't populate lookups for 12,000 rows.

Is there a technique to implement cascaded dropdowns without resorting to SPServices' implementation?  They require lookups.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  I inderstand the large data set.  But what do you mean by no lookup?  Do you mean the columns are not not set up as type Lookup?

Comment: Yes.  With 12,000 records I cannot create the lookup fields to link the lists.  However, just as in a database, I have the proper foreign keys in place.  I just need to specify the other list and filter based on the current selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SPServices SPCascadingDropdown will not work (I don't remember: it may require the columns to be of type Lookup) then my suggestion is to either fork it and modify it to do the cascading on regular (non-Lookup) fields or take a look at Marks code for that utility and roll your own. 
The approach would be for you to replace the text fields on the form with Select lists (I would hide the originals (not delete them) and keep them in sync with the value selected in the new Select) and then populate the select elements them with the data from your lists. 
Good luck.